# Sum values in two different tables and join results keeping the columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables: one with downtime and the other with productive time.

[image: Table with productive time]

[image: Downtime]

I want to have a table like this

[image]

But I am getting this

[image]

In the result, I am getting twice the downtime of the sum for the report 04102021-1, but as can be seen in the second picture, the value is present only once.
The script I am using is the following:

```
SELECT WAJ.REPORTCODE,--BASIC_REPORT_TABLE.TECHNICIAN,BASIC_REPORT_TABLE.JOBREPORTCODE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND,WAJ.TIMESTARTED,WAJ.TIMEFINISHED)<0 
     THEN (86400+DATEDIFF(SECOND,WAJ.TIMESTARTED,WAJ.TIMEFINISHED))/3600.0
     ELSE DATEDIFF(SECOND,WAJ.TIMESTARTED,WAJ.TIMEFINISHED) /3600.0
     END) AS PRODUCTION_TIME,
     
     SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND,WAS.TIMESTARTED,WAS.TIMEFINISHED)<0 
     THEN (86400+DATEDIFF(SECOND,WAS.TIMESTARTED,WAS.TIMEFINISHED))/3600.0
     ELSE DATEDIFF(SECOND,WAS.TIMESTARTED,WAS.TIMEFINISHED) /3600.0
     END) AS DOWNTIME
    
      FROM WORK_AT_JOB WAJ,WAITING_AT_SITE WAS

WHERE (WAJ.REPORTCODE=WAS.REPORTCODE AND WAJ.REPORTCODE LIKE '04102021%') GROUP BY WAJ.REPORTCODE
```

After the @xQbert comment, I tried this:

```
SELECT WAS.REPORTCODE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND,WAJ.TIMESTARTED,WAJ.TIMEFINISHED)<0 
     THEN (86400+DATEDIFF(SECOND,WAJ.TIMESTARTED,WAJ.TIMEFINISHED))/3600.0
     ELSE DATEDIFF(SECOND,WAJ.TIMESTARTED,WAJ.TIMEFINISHED) /3600.0
     END) AS PRODUCTION_TIME, 
     
     SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND,WAS.TIMESTARTED,WAS.TIMEFINISHED)<0 
     THEN (86400+DATEDIFF(SECOND,WAS.TIMESTARTED,WAS.TIMEFINISHED))/3600.0
     ELSE DATEDIFF(SECOND,WAS.TIMESTARTED,WAS.TIMEFINISHED) /3600.0
     END) AS DOWNTIME
     
      FROM WAITING_AT_SITE WAS 
      JOIN WORK_AT_JOB WAJ
      ON (WAJ.REPORTCODE=WAS.REPORTCODE AND WAS.REPORTCODE LIKE '04102021%') GROUP BY WAS.REPORTCODE
```

But I got the same result.
May you give some advice to get the result I want?
Thanks in advance

Comment: options 1) do the aggregration in sub queries or common table expressions before you join .  2) use analytic functions to do the sums and partition by the keys of the respective tables.  The issue is the cardinality of the table joins 1:M or M:M is causing your totals to multiply by the number of rows involved.  So you need to sum before the joins; or sum independant of the rows in the other table; which a analytic can do; or suming before the joins would do.

Comment: Give either of the above a shot; if you have trouble post what you've tried and we'll give guidance.  Or someone will likely come in and post a solution in the next 30 minutes without giving you the opportunity to learn given the above guidance :P

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Good use of whitespace wouldn't go amiss, and I'm sorry but ALL-CAPS is hurting my eyes

Comment: Thank you very much for the guys that help me with ideas to answer the question. I would like to mention that I do not agree with the fact that you punish the question only because it doesn't have the right format. If someone else looks for a solution, he/she will think that is not valuable because of the rate of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation for this, but the easiest, and probably most performant, way to do this is to pre-aggregate the results before you join.

```sql
SELECT
  waj.REPORTCODE
  waj.PRODUCTION_TIME,
  was.DOWNTIME    
FROM (
    SELECT
      waj.REPORTCODE,
      SUM(CASE WHEN v.diff < 0 THEN 86400 + v.diff ELSE v.diff END / 3600.0) AS PRODUCTION_TIME
    FROM WORK_AT_JOB waj
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES( DATEDIFF(SECOND, waj.TIMESTARTED, waj.TIMEFINISHED) )) v(diff)
    WHERE waj.REPORTCODE LIKE '04102021%'
    GROUP BY
      waj.REPORTCODE
) waj
JOIN (
    SELECT
      was.REPORTCODE,
      SUM(CASE WHEN v.diff < 0 THEN 86400 + v.diff ELSE v.diff END / 3600.0) AS PRODUCTION_TIME
    FROM WAITING_AT_SITE was
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES( DATEDIFF(SECOND, was.TIMESTARTED, was.TIMEFINISHED) )) v(diff)
    WHERE was.REPORTCODE LIKE '04102021%'
    GROUP BY
      was.REPORTCODE
) was ON waj.REPORTCODE = was.REPORTCODE;
```

Note the use of `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` to avoid code repetition.

Comment: Thank you very much @Charlieface. I could solve the issue.

Comment: @DorianOria  So if this is the accepted answer please mark it as such.  This is what I was alluding to when I said do the aggregation before the join.  Note the inline queries do the aggregation prior to the join.  Cheers! Glad whatever you had worked out.  If this isn't the accepted answer; post your solution and accept it to help others.